# Printing to text file using Python

Tags: python, text-files

I have written the following code and have executed it several times:

```
import statements....

#Scrape some information....
text_file = open("Output.txt", "w")
text_file.write('some text')
for each in array:
   #some code to find the value of row...
   text_file.write(str(row.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')))
   print (row.encode('ascii', errors='ignore'))
text_file.close()
```

However, only the 'some text' is written to the file. I have printed the row text and it produces the correct output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That code won't work. You'll get an `IndexError` and you need `range` to iterate on the array or simply iterate on the array directly

Comment: @MosesKoledoye The code executes fine and prints the right output. However, it is not written to the file.

Comment: that looks like it should work, you sure is not that you have the output file open somewhere else like a text editor and that is causing some interference/confusion? if so, close those, run the code and then check the file. Also, the recommended way to work with files is with the `with` statement

Comment: @Copperfield Nope, the text file isn't open. Running in Atom v1.12.7 using Script package.

Comment: create minimal, working example with this problem or show full code. Maybe your code opens file many times and last time `array` is empty so it writes only `'some text'` and delete previous text (because you use `w` mode)

Comment: mmm, and I suppose you don't modify or touch the file in any way in some other part or your code, right? and are you sure that the file you are checking is the correct one in the same folder as the scrip and not some other one with a similar name and/or some other folder?

Comment: I also think your code should work. Could you try to change the code `text_file.write(str(row.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')))` to `text_file.write('ok\n')` to see whether the `ok\n`-s are writed into the `Output.txt`? If yes, then you should check what it's returned in `str(row.encode('ascii', errors='ignore'))`.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in as open("Output.txt", "a") instead of just "w". This will allow you to append the rest of the text.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Have Fun!

Comment: Did that but received this error: `ValueError: must have exactly one of create/read/write/append mode`

Comment: I think the error is pretty verbose. Python doesn't take mixes of file modes as parameter in `open()`. Replace `wa` with `a`.